# Output redirection and spaces

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script

I'm paranoid about this, but hopefully it's a simple question:

Is there any difference between

```
cat file1 | egrep -oP "[Mm]y string" > /home/user/file.txt
```

and

```
cat file1|egrep -oP "[Mm]y string">/home/user/file.txt
```

i.e., does it matter if I have spaces padding the pipe (|) and redirection (>) characters? I'm really paranoid that having spaces there the spaces will somehow end up in the output file when I don't want that. Can anyone clarify? (Using Ubuntu 12/bash if that matters.)

Comment: The only differences are a) cosmetic and b) convenience when editing command lines in bash - e.g. a "word" is delimited by spaces, so without spaces around `|` or `>` then typing `Ctrl-W` to delete the previous "word" would delete more than you probably wanted.  ditto for cursor-movement keystrokes like `Esc-f` and `Esc-b` etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the shell command line, *unquoted* spaces only serve to delimit words during command parsing.  They are not passed on, neither in the arguments the command sees nor in the standard input stream.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a security vulnerability with using a space after the operators? I am having a hard time reproducing it now, but there is a common exploit where a malicious user can change the intended operation by using a file like " fileName" when the intended file was "fileName".